# Given an interface property, get the type of a matching key from a different interface

Tags: typescript

I'm faced with a situation where I have many pairs of interfaces. These interfaces have matching keys, but different types.

```
interface A {
  foo: string
  bar: number
}

interface B {
  foo: { id: string }
  bar: boolean
}
```

I also have a type which sort of "instantiates" these interfaces with generics, and also adds an extra property:

```
type WrapperType<T> = { extraProp: string } & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }
```

An instance of the wrapper type would look like this

```
const x: WrapperType<A> = {
  extraProp: "Hello",
  foo: "World",
  bar: 10,
}
```

What I'm trying to write is a function which takes in a key of `WrapperType<T>` and enforces the second argument's to be it's "sister" interface's matching property type. I don't even know if this is possible.

I'm not sure where even to start, maybe something like this?

```
declare function doSomething<???>(arg1: keyof WrapperType<T>, arg2: ???): T;
```

What I would like is for the user to type this in:

```
doSomething(x.foo,
```

and be prompted with arg2's type of `{ id: string }` since that is the matching type in B, which is the "sister" interface to A.

This single function should also work for any arbitrary pair of interfaces, not just these two.

I was thinking of defining a type like this to relate the two interfaces:

```
type RelatedType<T> = T extends A ? B : T extends C ? D : ... for all interface pairs in my library
```

although I'm not sure how to use a relation like this within a function to enforce parameter types.

I'm a bit new to typescript, and I'm not sure if this is doable or if I'm even headed in the right direction here.

**EDIT**

I've managed to make some progress. I have a function that now takes the wrapper object and a property string

```
interface A {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}

interface B {
    foo: { id: string }
    bar: boolean
}

type MyWrapper<T> = { name: string } & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }

const a: MyWrapper<A> = {
    name: "a",
    foo: "foo",
    bar: 10,
}

type RelatedType<T> = T extends A ? B : never

type RelativeType<T extends keyof S, S> = T extends keyof RelatedType<S> ? Pick<RelatedType<S>, T>[T] : never

declare function doSomething<I, P extends keyof I>(obj: MyWrapper<I>, property: P, arg: RelativeType<P, I>): I;

const test = doSomething(a, "foo", { id: "hello" }) // 3rd arg correctly infer type!
```

But my end goal here is to instead of passing in `a` and `"foo"` as two separate arguments, I simply would like to pass in `a.foo` as the first argument.

Comment: That `WrapperType` with the extra property seems like a needless complication; can we ignore it for now?  How would `doSomething()` work with "an arbitrary pair of interfaces" exactly?  How does it know when you call `doSomething(arg1, arg2)` which two interfaces to be looking at?  If you want you can do something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRA7XW) shows... does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the suggestion. Your questions sort of another way to phrase what I'm asking. If I need to define some other data structures which relate these pairs, that's fine. I know I need some way to explicitly relate these interfaces with each other, just not sure how. I will look at your suggestion in a bit.

Comment: @jcalz unfortunately this doesn't work for my needs. I need to find a way to sort of link these two interfaces together, or perhaps use an entirely different data structure to be able to relate the two types.

Comment: What, *specifically*, doesn't work for your needs? Could you [edit] the question to be clearer? From what you've written my suggestion is as close as I can imagine getting; if you need something else it would help if you'd spell it out.

Comment: @jcalz Specifically, we've defeated the purpose of what I'm trying to do by defining a specific function to work for just A and B. What I need is a general function which works for any given pair. That is to say, if a.foo is given, the type of b.foo should be required. If x.foo is given, the type of (some sister interface which is defined Y) y.foo should be required.

Comment: @jcalz I've added some extra info to hopefully give some more insight.

Comment: Hmm, the *names* of values don't exist anywhere; if `x.foo === a.bar` then calling `doSomething(x.foo, arg2)` is identical to `doSomething(a.bar, arg2)`, so there's no way even in principle to decide that `arg2` should correspond to `y.foo` vs `b.bar`.  You absolutely need to call something like `doSomething("X", x.foo, y.foo)` vs `doSomething("A", a.bar, y.bar)`.  Would that be acceptable?  If so I'll show a solution for that.  If not then either you haven't thought through the implications of what you're asking for, or I'm still confused about what you're asking for, or both.

Comment: @jcalz I just did another edit. Does my solution look something like you were proposing?

Comment: Sort of?  If I use your approach I get [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/mxyxKW).  Do you understand why `doSomething(x.foo, y.foo)` is impossible?

Comment: @jcalz Hm, your approach seems to still require a string value given, which is unfortunate. The last line of your example is OK. I am not working with object of type B or type Z. These "sister" interfaces are simply supposed to be defined as a "lookup" for the respective type of the first given interface.

That is to say, it doesn't matter if there's overlap. All that matters is that the correct type is inferred from the sister interface.

Comment: @jcalz In a wider scope, my goal here is to assocate the properties of interface A with two different types without modifying A so that I can return a pure A object from `doSomething`. This is how I thought initially of doing it. But if you have any other ways that we might be able to associate A.foo with both `string` and `{ id: string }` and use those two types in the context of the function, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in pursuing this if the scope is widened; I've presented multiple solutions and I'm still not sure if you understand why `doSomething(x.foo, y.foo)` is impossible to do.  I think I need to disengage now, unfortunately. If you have some specific (possible) idea that you'd like to implement, and you [edit] to explicitly mention that, I'll take another look.  Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz No problem. I think I understand that given `a.foo`, there's no way to actually grab the name of the property itself (since you said that names doesn't actually exist).

However I'm kind of surprised by this. Does typescript not offer any sort of reflection  that would allow me to pull a given property's name as a string and use it?

Comment: TypeScript does not offer reflection; it's one of the basic principles of TypeScript: [its type system is *erased* upon compilation to JS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types).  All I can think of here is to make your call explicitly mention one input type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQb07N), but I don't see how any implementation of `doSomething()` would be useful; what would it *do* without runtime information?  Anyway I'm going to run away screaming now